# How to design my html code inside my asp.net code?

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

How can i put some design in my HTML code inside the vb.net code?
I want to change the font design inside my body tag as the text in my body tag will send in users email address. Your help will greatly appreciated.

here's my code:

```
    mail.Subject = "SYSTEM REQUEST FORM " & txtRequestTitle.Text & " " & Format(Now(), "MM/dd/yyyy").ToString
                        mail.IsBodyHtml = True
                        mail.Body = "<html>" & _
                           "<body>" & _
                                "Dear " & DropDownApprover.Text & ",<br><br>" & _
                                "" & "The following request has been created and need your approval" & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "===============================================" & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "http://10.190.193.162/ITrequestform/LoginPage.aspx" & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "===============================================" & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "Requested By: " & lblName.Text & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "Need to Approve By: " & DropDownApprover.Text & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "===============================================" & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "Request Title: " & txtRequestTitle.Text & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "Request Category: " & DropDownCateg.Text & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "Request Item: " & DropDownCateg2.Text & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "Date Needed: " & txtDateNeeded.Text & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "===============================================" & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "For Employee: " & txtRequestEmp.Text & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "Position: " & txtEmpPost.Text & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "Description of Request: " & txtDescription.Text & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "Justification of Request: " & txtJustification.Text & "<br>" & _
                                "" & "<br>" & _
                                "Thanks," & "<br>" & _
                                "HKT Teleservices""<br>" & _
                            "</body>" & _
                          "</html>"
```

Comment: You can use basic css, see https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support/

Answer (score 1):

**Add CSS in project:**
In SolutionExplorer --> Right click o project --> Add existing item and select Stylesheet(CSS).

**Use CSS in ASPX page:**
You need to add refererence for this CSS file in ASPX page

```
<link href="Stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Any style you want to apply to your body text you can write in the code below
And in the `Stylesheet.css` file, , write this code

```
body{
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue" , "Lucida Grande" , "Segoe UI";
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: OP is creating an HTML email, so external style sheets are not going to work reliably.

Comment: Thank for the help, i just did the design inside my body tag :)